# Symbols in Google spreadsheet is visible as a box. Even on searching google symbols are displaying as boxes which wasn't the case few days back

Tags: google-sheets, unicode, symbols, spreadsheet, box

Does anyone know how to view actual symbol in google spreadsheet instead of the boxes. just few days back a symbol "raised comma" was visible as is, however it has been shown as a box now. Even when i am searching for the symbol on other sites only boxes are visible to me. [image]

Comment: The font used has to support the glyph for the symbol.

Comment: `‴` {Unicode _U+2034_, UTF-8 byte sequence `0xE2`, `0x80`, `0xB4`} *Triple Prime* while *Raised Comma* is *U+2E34*…

Comment: Do I need to install glyph typography? although it was working before. Please let me know which font style should I use in google spreadsheet @MarkTolonen As I changed the font as well but got the same box and not the raised comma.

Comment: @JosefZ I used 2E34 only, but getting box only as output. If I am searching the same on google then also the symbol is shown as a box.

Comment: `⸴` [_Raised Comma_ (`&#x2E34;`)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2E34) is rendered properly by a few fonts only, e.g. `Noto Sans`, `Noto Serif`, `Segoe UI`, `Tahoma`, `Times New Roman`, `Unifont` on my box.